# best time complexity to check if binary tree is avl tree (height balanced)

Tags: time-complexity, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

So I was asked in an interview, if its possible that checking if tree is avl tree, could be :
T(n) = O(log(n))

and didn't know the answer, after searching in google, the best algorithms I saw was O(n) ("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-determine-if-a-binary-tree-is-balanced/")

is it to make algorithm with O(log(n))?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends a bit. If the balance factors are explititly stored in the nodes, checking for balance could be done in `O(1)` time by reading the value from the root node; so suppose that the balance factors are not explicitly stored.

Note that in `O(log n)` time, it is impossible to read the entire input.